# Use 'new' in constructor? c++

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

Say I have two classes, myclass1 and myclass2. And suppose myclass2 has a field myclass1 object1. So the myclass2 header looks something like this:

```
 class myclass2 {
      public:
             myclass2();
             myclass2(int arg);
      private:
             myclass1 object1;
}
```

And suppose myclass1 has a header like this:

```
 class myclass1 {
      public:
             myclass1();
             myclass1(int arg);
      private:
             int var1;
}
```

Now suppose in my main function I want to instantiate an object of type myclass2, like so:

```
int main(){

         myclass2 object2(int VAR);

}
```

Then in order for object2's private field object1 to have private field var1 set equal to VAR upon instantiation of object2, should the constructor for myclass2 be like this(?):

```
myclass2::myclass2(int arg){
         object1 = object1(arg);
```

}

Or would this work(?):

```
   myclass2::myclass2(int arg){
         object1(arg);
```

}

Or in this situation must I have a mutator function in myclass1 to access object1's private field var1 in the constructor for myclass2?

Finally, would this do the job(?):

```
 myclass2::myclass2(int arg){
         myclass1 *type1pointer;
         type1pointer = new myclass1(arg);
         object1 = *type1pointer;
```

}

Comment: `myclass2 object2(int VAR);` in main is not what you think... It is a function declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class myclass2 {
public:
    myclass2(int arg) : object1(arg) {}
private:
    myclass1 object1;
};
```

Thus you initialize your object only once.
This way, object1 default constructor isn't called, thus avoiding default-constucting and then a specific `myclass1` mutator

Comment: Arf, you beat me to it x)

Comment: Could you add to your anwer the fact that this way, object1 default ctor isn't called, thus avoiding default-constucting and then calling the specific ctor ?